# Script to migrate data between two SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-migration

I have two SQL Server databases, and I need to write a script to migrate data from database A to database B. Both databases have the same schema.

I must loop through the tables and for each table I must follow those rules:

1. If the item I'm migrating does not exist in the target table (for example, the comparison is made on a column `Name`) then I insert it directly.
2. If the item I'm migrating exists in the target table then I need to only update certain columns (for example, only update `Age` and `Address` but do not touch other columns)

Can anyone help me with that script? Any example would suffice. Thanks a lot

**EDIT:**

I just need an example for one table. No need to loop, I can handle each table separately (because each table has its own comparison column and update columns)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MERGE statement looks like it can help you here. An Example:

```
MERGE StudentTotalMarks AS stm
USING (SELECT StudentID,StudentName FROM StudentDetails) AS sd
ON stm.StudentID = sd.StudentID
WHEN MATCHED AND stm.StudentMarks > 250 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET stm.StudentMarks = stm.StudentMarks + 25
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(StudentID,StudentMarks)
VALUES(sd.StudentID,25);
```

The merge statement is available as of SQL Server 2008 so you are in luck

Comment: What if the Tables are in different databases?

Comment: Hi Youssef. Merging across different databases is supported, just  use the fully qualified database name. More info: http://mikebosch.net/2010/08/using-the-merge-t-sql-command-across-databases-on-sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a script why don't you copy the source table under a different name into the target server (update needs to take place).

Then just do a simple insert where name does not exist.

Here is the SQL for step 1 only.

```
INSERT INTO [TableA]
SELECT Name,
       XX,
       XXXX
FROM   TableB
WHERE  NOT NAME IN(SELECT NAME
                   FROM   TableA)
```